How to retrieve product details from amazon catalog?
We are a digital marketing company trying to integrate with amazon to create campaigns and post ads through our platform using Amazon Ads API. Now, we want to list all the products and its details from a particular marketplace into our platform so that advertiser can select the product for which ad is to be displayed.
This is possible using the Amazon Product Advertising API but we need to pass ASINs in request to fetch the details and we dont have ASINs. Is there any way that product details can be fetched without ASINs. We want the products to be pre-populated and updated from catalog before hand, may be by using profile id.
We also tried using Selling partner API but same issue that we need to pass ASIN.

The Product ID also known as ASIN can be found on the Amazon retail website. You can locate the ASIN on the product detail page under the Product Details section. Simply go to the product detail page and you'll find the ASIN listed there.
